# Sql query to manipulate day, year and month in a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Update:** I want to push the dates forward because the anniversary date is incorrect in the table for some reasons.**I am trying to update the Anniversary date to next future date for an employee whose anniversary date already passed for the current date**

I have some incorrect **anniversary dates** in one of my Table and want to write a logic to fix that. Logic is:

**Use case 1 :** Employee 1 Anniversary Date = `15th June,2020`, `Current date = 26,June,2022`  (already in database). `This is invalid date`.

Employee 1 new Anniversary Date should be = `1st July,2022 (New update date)`. `This will be a correct date.`

**Use case 2 :** Employee 2 Anniversary Date = `15th June,2020`, `Current date = 26,July,2022` (already in database).`This is invalid date`

Employee 2 new Anniversary Date should be = `1st July,2023` `(New update date)`.`This will be a correct date.`

**Use Case 3:** Employee 3 Anniversary Date = `1st February,2022`, `current date = 26,July,2022 (already in database)`.

Employee 3 new Anniversary Date should be = `1st March,2023 (New update date)`

**Sql Query:**

```
Update Employee
set Anniversarydate =  CASE 
            WHEN (YEAR(Anniversarydate) < YEAR(GETDATE()) and
                        month(Anniversarydate) < Month(GETDATE())) 
            then 'manipulate date here'--How do i manupulate date here with my logic
            ELSE 'do nothing'
            End
where (YEAR(Anniversarydate) < YEAR(GETDATE())) and (YEAR(Anniversarydate) < YEAR(GETDATE()) and
month(Anniversarydate) < Month(GETDATE()))
```

Can someone please help or guide me?

Comment: Why not build a query to get the data you want every year? Instead you are loosing historical data from your database. Also it is not clear why the dates are incorrect or what exact is your logic (both are valid dates). Specifically it is not clear if you want your logic to push the anniversary date forward (or backwards for that matter), it is not clear what you consider invalid, it is not clear what should happen if the date is not 15th of the month... As you can see a little bit more of explanation will help us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have updated the question with more info. Can you please take a look now and let me know if its still not clear. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeCampos We dont care about the date when comparing. We only care about the month and year

Comment: Sorry, your update didn't clarify it enough. This is really looking like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why a valid date is considered "invalid", how should we know when to consider something invalid? `15th June,2020` is a valid date, and in the context of anniversary of an employee in a company it is valid, and should be kept as is. Are you trying to get a next valid future date for an employee in which his anniversary date already passed?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, correct. I am trying to update the Anniversary date to next future date for an employee whose anniversary date already passed.

Comment: So, please update your question to state that. Although that can be done, I would highly recommend you not to. Anniversary date is the date an employee started in a company and should not be changed AT ALL. You use it as reference to compute it and return the computed version of it based on current date. If you are doing this while working for a company, you are probably going the wrong way, now if this is just a learning experience it is ok. I will add a solution for you, that is if no one beats me to it :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sure, I will update my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246788/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: Can you please add sample table data and your expected output so that it will be more clear?

Comment: Please read this : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1):

So as mentioned and discussed in the comments here is a solution that will give you the updated dates WITHOUT changing anything to your database, as `anniversary date` of an employee is an important date and should not be changed:

```
SELECT Anniversarydate, 
       case when DATEADD(YEAR, 
                         DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                  Anniversarydate) < GETDATE() 
          then DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
          else DATEADD(YEAR,
                       DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                       Anniversarydate) end computed
  FROM Employee
```

Now if you still want to update it here is the command you need to use:

```
update Employee 
   set Anniversarydate = case when DATEADD(YEAR, 
                         DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                  Anniversarydate) < GETDATE() 
          then DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
          else DATEADD(YEAR,
                       DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                       Anniversarydate) end
 where Anniversarydate < GETDATE();
```

Check it working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9322138cb4827100946bf6b6f682eaf8

**UPDATED**
This will give you the first day of the month for all dates even in future

```
update Employee 
   set Anniversarydate = case when DATEADD(YEAR, 
                         DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                  Anniversarydate) < GETDATE() 
          then DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
          else DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(YEAR,
                                     DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                     Anniversarydate)),-1)) end
 where Anniversarydate < GETDATE();
```

See it working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49534bf70138730bb2b782b0ca2b2e8b

**UPDATE 2**

```
update Employee 
   set Anniversarydate = 
 case when year(Anniversarydate) < year(GETDATE()) 
            then DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
          when year(Anniversarydate) = year(GETDATE()) and month(Anniversarydate) < month(GETDATE())
            then DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(YEAR,
                                     DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                     Anniversarydate))))
          else DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(YEAR,
                                     DATEDIFF(Year,Anniversarydate,GETDATE()),
                                     Anniversarydate))))
          end;
```

See it working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ca3e49a8482c6014fc08c1e230356d6

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but I always want the first day of next month but currently for "2020-08-15 10:34:09.000" output is "2022-08-15 10:34:09.000" but I always want first day of month.

Comment: That can be easily fixed. Let me do it.

Comment: Done! Added the updated version

Comment: When i add a new record with this date "20220201 10:34:09 AM" then calculated one is "2022-08-01 00:00:00.000". Can you try this use case?

Comment: As per the requirement this is correct. "I am trying to update the Anniversary date to next future date for an employee whose anniversary date already passed" `20220201 10:34:09 AM` it is already a past date. This is why it is important to get your logic well explained. To prevent further back and forth, could you please add a list of scenarios with the dates and then what would be the expected behaviour for it? Though if you are just trying to not update the ones from current year just adding to the `where` : `and YEAR(Anniversarydate) < YEAR(GETDATE())` would resolve your problem

Comment: I have added use case 3 in my question. so if the anniversary year is equal to current year but the anniversary month is less than current month (means already passed) hence we set the year to next year and month is always going to be the 1st of next month.

Comment: I updated adding more cases. If the last one date after today is not valid that is, pushing the date to the next valid month, you just need to add the where clause `where Anniversarydate < GETDATE()`. I still think this makes no sense and if this is a requirement in a company please review it the chances you misunderstood it are high.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246801/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but I guess it’s still failing with some of the dates. For eg: 
“2020-06-15 10:34:09.000” returns “2022-08-01” which is wrong. It should return “2023-07-01” because “June” is already passed hence year changes to next year “2023” and also month is always going to be the first day of next month.

Comment: Same problem with the date “2020-07-15” and “2020-15-08”

Comment: I will stop now. Please edit your question in accordance to this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question . Again, I mentioned several times now why it is important to clarify your question. Once your have that I can It is impossible to provide a good answer without all the necessary details which your question is still lacking A LOT. So please careful read above post and edit your question accordingly. I will then resume on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure no problem. Thank you so much for helping me. You have already helped a lot. Really appreciate it